# Multiple Devices, One Ethernet Jack, MAC Filtering

Tags: router, mac-address, ethernet

So, in my college dorm, theres wifi for the students as well as a single ethernet jack. Problem is, this ethernet jack is MAC filtered, and can only allow one mac address to use it at a time. This can however be switched back and forth from the school's website, but can sometimes take up to a half hour to update. I have my desktop using it right now, but want to bring up my PS4 when I go back, but will not be able to easily access the internet. It is impossible to connect it to the wifi with a game console (from my own experiences and what the school has told me), since a wifi profile & login information is required, which the PS4 simply can't do. Plus, its unreliable. So I'd like to run it through the ethernet jack with my PC.

My only ideas so far have been to buy a single port lan card for my computer so I can run an ethernet cable out to the PS4, effectively bridging the connection through software in Windows. However, I'm worried that this will still cause an issue with the mac address filter. Would connections coming from my PS4 through my PC to the jack appear only from my PC (problem solved)? Or as a separate mac address?

Another idea was to get a router, which can be set up through the jack, but seems like an unnecessary amount of hassle.

Any ideas? Thanks guys.
Mark

Comment: Can't you just use a router? Don't they have their own MACs?

Answer (score 1):

Use a router box in NAT mode : no one will see in your single-ethernet-jack how many devices are behind because of MAC masqerade. From your school's network equipment point of view it will be as a single device - but inside you'll have a full private network of your own design. A small note : use Tor or VPN channeling if you'll be a victim of an inner firewall

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bridging, that is effectively the same thing as putting an Ethernet switch on the network - it performs Layer-2 routing (which is the MAC layer). Bridging will cause the SysAdmins to see *both* your devices on the network.

You can, however, set up your computer to "share your internet connection" which effectively turns it into a router (a NAT gateway, to be technical). This is the same thing as a router. However, a router is easy: you get it, plug it in, and it works; internet sharing only works when the computer is on and sometimes needs to be rebooted and re set up.

Also, this question is off-topic and belongs in the super-user stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you. A router is probably the way I'll go then. And I apologize, I'm new to SE and wasn't familiar with the other parts of the site.